# AngularJS make Id-s for objects in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, master-detail

I am pretty new to programming and I have a very frustrating problem. I really have spent hours to find an answer but I failed.

So basically I am working on a Master Detailed `todo` list. My `todos` are objects in an array. I am at the point where I should make the different views for the master-detail thing, but I can't separate the objects by ID.

Here is my AngularJS code:

```
myTodoList.controller("mainController", ['$scope', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.todos = [{
        'id': 0,
        'title': '',
        'done': false,
        'priority': '',
        'deadLine': '',
    }];

    $scope.$route = $route;
    $scope.$location = $location;
    $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
    $scope.params = $routeParams;
    $scope.todos = [];

    $scope.addTodo = function(title, priority, deadLine, id) {
        $scope.todos.push({
            'id': $scope.todos.id,
            'title': $scope.newTodo,
            'done': false,
            'priority': $scope.newPriority,
            'deadLine': $scope.newDeadLine
        });
        $scope.newTodo = ''
        $scope.newPriority = ''
        $scope.newDeadLine = ''
        $scope.todos.id++;
    }
```

In this case when I try to create routes by :id it says that it is NAN (Not a Number I quess). But if I change the code to:

```
$scope.addTodo = function(title, priority, deadLine, id) {
        $scope.todos.push({
            'id': 0,
            'title': $scope.newTodo,
            'done': false,
            'priority': $scope.newPriority,
            'deadLine': $scope.newDeadLine
        });
        $scope.newTodo = ''
        $scope.newPriority = ''
        $scope.newDeadLine = ''
        $scope.todos.id++;
    }
```

This, so the `'id': 0`, then all todos get the number 0 as in ID. It's been 3 days since I can't make this thing right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using an array to hold the last id, but the problem is that you are not initializing the id;

```
var id;
id++; //NAN
```

Javascript is very *lose* as you can see, you can add properties to arrays and use operators on undefined variable without getting any error. In your case, `$scope.todos.id = 0;` right after initializing the array should fix the problem.

But it would be better to hold the last id in another variable, and it doesn't need to be in the scope, just `var lastId = 0;` and `lastId++` is enough.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot. I remember that I tried something like that but I guess I messed up at some point that too. I have another problem, my expressions don't work in the new view I am working on. But  I am ging to dive into the internet to find the solution. :)

Thank you for helping me out I really appreciate it!!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I can help. Learning to program could be very frustrating sometimes, but once you get it, it's awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.todos` is an array, so the line `'id': $scope.todos.id` can't work.

Change it for:

```
$scope.todos.push({
    'id': $scope.todos[0].id // <-- here
    'title': $scope.newTodo,
    'done': false,
    'priority': $scope.newPriority,
    'deadLine': $scope.newDeadLine
});
```

It is the synthax to use the first element of the array.